# cant add language in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, locale

I cant add a new language in the dropdown of laravel app... I added the "bn" folder in the resource/lang folder and also added the file bn.json

it is saying

```
ErrorException
Undefined array key "bn"
```

plz help

this is my config file in config folder

```
<?php

/*
 * All configuration options for Laravel Boilerplate
 * http://laravel-boilerplate.com.
 */

return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Access
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Configurations related to the boilerplate's access/authorization options
    */
    'access' => [
        'captcha' => [
            'configs' => [
                'site_key' => env('INVISIBLE_RECAPTCHA_SITEKEY'),
                'secret_key' => env('INVISIBLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRETKEY'),
                'options' => [
                    'hidden' => false,
                    'location' => 'bottomright',
                    'timeout' => 5,
                ],
            ],
            'login' => env('LOGIN_CAPTCHA_STATUS', false),
            'registration' => env('REGISTRATION_CAPTCHA_STATUS', false),
        ],

        'middleware' => [
            'confirm' => 'password.confirm:frontend.auth.password.confirm',
            'verified' => 'verified:frontend.auth.verification.notice',
        ],

        'user' => [
            /*
             * Whether or not admins need 2FA enabled to visit the backend
             */
            'admin_requires_2fa' => env('ADMIN_REQUIRES_2FA', true),

            /*
             * Whether or not a user can change their email address after
             * their account has already been created
             */
            'change_email' => env('CHANGE_EMAIL', true),

            /*
             * When creating users from the backend, only allow the assigning of roles and not individual permissions
             */
            'only_roles' => false,

            /*
             * How many days before users have to change their passwords
             * false is off
             */
            'password_expires_days' => env('PASSWORD_EXPIRES_DAYS', 180),

            /*
             * The number of most recent previous passwords to check against when changing/resetting a password
             * false is off which doesn't log password changes or check against them
             *
             * Note: Enabling single_login will have an effect on this as it force changes the users password on login,
             * which will force a record into the password_histories table. I currently do not have a fix in mind.
             */
            'password_history' => env('PASSWORD_HISTORY', 3),

            /*
             * Whether or not a user can be permanently deleted from the system via the backend
             * The regular delete button will still exist, and will soft delete the user
             * but the permanently deleted button on the 'deleted users' screen will be hidden.
             */
            'permanently_delete' => false,

            /*
             * Whether or not the register route and view are active
             */
            'registration' => env('ENABLE_REGISTRATION', true),

            /*
             * When active, a user can only have one session active at a time
             * That is all other sessions for that user will be deleted when they log in
             * (They can only be logged into one place at a time, all others will be logged out)
             * AuthenticateSession middleware must be enabled
             */
            'single_login' => env('SINGLE_LOGIN', false),
        ],

        'role' => [

            /*
             * The name of the administrator role
             * Should be Administrator by design and unable to change from the backend
             * It is not recommended to change
             */
            'admin' => 'Administrator',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Avatar
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Configurations related to the boilerplate's avatar system
    */
    'avatar' => [

        /*
         * Default size of the avatar if none is supplied
         */
        'size' => 80,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Frontend Breadcrumbs
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Whether or not to show the breadcrumb trail on the frontend
    | Note: Turning this off does not unregister the breadcrumbs in the routes file, it just hides the navbar
    */
    'frontend_breadcrumbs' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Configurations related to the boilerplate's locale system
    */
    'locale' => [
        /*
         * Whether or not to show the language picker, or just default to the default
         * locale specified in the app config file
         */
        'status' => true,

        /*
         * Available languages
         *
         * Add your language code to this array.
         * The code must have the same name as the language folder.
         * Be sure to add the new language in an alphabetical order.
         *
         * The language picker will not be available if there is only one language option
         * Commenting out languages will make them unavailable to the user
         */
        'languages' => [
            'ar' => ['name' => 'Arabic', 'rtl' => true],
            'az' => ['name' => 'Azerbaijan', 'rtl' => false],
            'bn' => ['name' => 'Bangla', 'rtl' => true],
            'zh' => ['name' => 'Chinese Simplified', 'rtl' => false],
            'zh-TW' => ['name' => 'Chinese Traditional', 'rtl' => false],
            'cs' => ['name' => 'Czech', 'rtl' => false],
            'da' => ['name' => 'Danish', 'rtl' => false],
            'de' => ['name' => 'German', 'rtl' => false],
            'el' => ['name' => 'Greek', 'rtl' => false],
            'en' => ['name' => 'English', 'rtl' => false],

            'es' => ['name' => 'Spanish', 'rtl' => false],
            'fa' => ['name' => 'Persian', 'rtl' => true],
            'fr' => ['name' => 'French', 'rtl' => false],
            'he' => ['name' => 'Hebrew', 'rtl' => true],
            'id' => ['name' => 'Indonesian', 'rtl' => false],
            'it' => ['name' => 'Italian', 'rtl' => false],
            'ja' => ['name' => 'Japanese', 'rtl' => false],
            'ko' => ['name' => 'Korean', 'rtl' => false],
            'nl' => ['name' => 'Dutch', 'rtl' => false],
            'no' => ['name' => 'Norwegian', 'rtl' => false],
            'pl' => ['name' => 'Polish', 'rtl' => false],
            'pt_BR' => ['name' => 'Brazilian Portuguese', 'rtl' => false],
            'pt_PT' => ['name' => 'Portuguese', 'rtl' => false],
            'ro' => ['name' => 'Romana', 'rtl' => false],
            'ru' => ['name' => 'Russian', 'rtl' => false],
            'sv' => ['name' => 'Swedish', 'rtl' => false],
            'th' => ['name' => 'Thai', 'rtl' => false],
            'tr' => ['name' => 'Turkish', 'rtl' => false],
            'uk' => ['name' => 'Ukrainian', 'rtl' => false],
            'vi' => ['name' => 'Vietnam', 'rtl' => false],
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Testing Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is currently running tests
    |
    */
    'testing' => env('APP_TESTING', false),
];
```

this is my LocaleController code:

```
   <?PHP

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   /**
   * Class LocaleController.
   */
   class LocaleController
    {
    /**
     * @param $locale
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function change($locale)
    {
        app()->setLocale($locale);

        session()->put('locale', $locale);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

This is my lang.blade.php code

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownLanguageLink">
    @foreach(collect(config('boilerplate.locale.languages'))->sortBy('name') as $code => $details)

        @if($code !== app()->getLocale())
            <x-utils.link class="dropdown-item pt-1 pb-1" :href="route('locale.change', $code)" :text="__(getLocaleName($code))" />
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div><!--dropdown-menu-->
```

this is my kernel middlewareGroups code:

```
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\LocaleMiddleware::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Domains\Auth\Http\Middleware\ToBeLoggedOut::class,
        ],
```

This is my route code:

```
Route::get('lang/{lang}',
        [LocaleController::class, 'change'])
        ->name('locale.change');
```

Comment: @Tamin Wasifjd Maybe you check the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263088/laravel-language-picker?rq=1).

Comment: @Tinxuanna inthis post they have no error with the array element... but when I am adding the 'bn' element in the array this error occurs... why? default array can be defined I think...  or I should do anything else to define an array elements?

Comment: @Tamin Wasifjd In /config/app.php file, try to set the array named locales. There you can define the array element 'bn', As shown below:

'locales' => [
    'en' => 'English',
    'bn' => 'Bangla',
]

Comment: @Tamin Wasifjd Also, you should use _config:clear_ in order to update the changes made.

Comment: @Tinxuanna the problem is solved... i just deleted the project and created a new one... and then tried.. and now fixed.. thanks for your replay...